# proguard export application package

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I made android project.
If i make an export (signed or unsigned) application package on eclipse, it works.
If i launch obfuscation from proguardgui it works.
But if i launch an export application package after activating proguard i have this error:

```
[2015-03-03 15:37:20 - Toa] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-03-03 15:37:20 - Toa] Note: there were 1307 duplicate class definitions.
[2015-03-03 15:37:20 - Toa]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[2015-03-03 15:37:20 - Toa] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2015-03-03 15:37:20 - Toa] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I don't have any space in my sdk, android sdk or project path.
I update proguard to the last version.

is any body had the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make it work. So i decide to solve by making ant building.
It doesn't take a lot of time and it's realy more convenient to debug.